# What is .htaccess: Invalid command 'ess.swp'? Magento/Wampserver

Tags: magento-enterprise, error, htaccess, apache, wamp

I am trying to install our live Magento EE site on Wampserver but I am getting a 500 "Internal Server Error" and the below error in my Apache Error Log. I am being told on the Wampsever forum that I "may" have missed one or more Magento prerequisites seen in the link below but it "appears" I already met all the prerequisites?

**So what exactly is .htaccess: Invalid command 'ess.swp'?**

> 5] [core:alert] [pid 7960:tid 848] [client 127.0.0.1:56866]
>   C:/wamp/www/shopcandelabra/.htaccess: Invalid command 'ess.swp',
>   perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server
>   configuration, referer: [http://localhost/][1]

http://magento.com/resources/previous-magento-system-requirements

Comment: You might need to update the question with your. htaccess file code for better understanding your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! I had to comment out the line with "ess.swp" in my .htaccess file. I also had to comment out these lines (ExpiresActive, ExpiresByType) as they were also generated errors in the Apache Log.